Microsoft Entra ID and .NET Framework (Web Forms) - get user details to validate a local login
we need to integrate Entra ID login on a web application (.NET Web Forms based) but I'm not convinced about the approach.
Our application has a deep characterization of the user permissions, so we have to manage a local profile and automate the login consuming an Entra ID authentication. The idea is to give users the opportunity to make a SSO with Entra ID and have a mechanism that, reading a value from the Azure response, creates a local login session for the user.
We succeded on integrating ENTRA ID login on out app starting with the Visual Studio template, but with some issues:

we had to maintain the standard anonymous authentication, because if we remove it the web app forces users to log with Entra ID before everything: this is not a desired behaviour, we want to maintain also a local (MFA) login, the Entra ID SSO must be a choice

we have now an authentication process where, after a successful ENTRA ID login, the request is authenticated with ENTRA ID user details: we consume them, create a local session and then force a logout from ENTRA ID.


I would like to ask for a SSO login against ENTRA ID and only check the answer searching for the needed values without authentincating against the application, because I have no benefit from this. Any ideas about managing this kind of situation?
